# Show that $[[H,J],K]\neq [H,[J,K]]$

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G=S_3$ Show that there are subgroups $H,J,K$ of $G$ such that
>
> $$[[H,J],K]\neq [H,[J,K]] \tag{*} $$

I am studying group theory currently and this question is from Rose's "A Course on Group Theory" and I have just seen this notation in $(*)$ What does it simply mean?
Current edit:

Am I allowed to do the following in order to show  $[[H,J],K]\neq [H,[J,K]]$
$$[[H,J],K]=[\big < HJH^{-1}J^{-1} \big >,K]=\big <(hjh^{-1}j^{-1})k(hjh^{-1}j^{-1})^{-1}k^{-1}\big >= \big <hjh^{-1}j^{-1}kjhj^{-1}h^{-1}k^{-1}\big >$$ whereas $$[H,[J,K]]=[H,\big < JKJ^{-1}K^{-1} \big >]=\big <h(jkj^{-1}k^{-1})h^{-1}(jkj^{-1}k^{-1})^{-1}\big >=\big <hjkj^{-1}k^{-1}h^{-1}kjk^{-1}j^{-1}\big >$$
The subgroups of $S_3$ are:

$1,S_3,\big <(12)\big >,\big <(13)\big >,\big <(23)\big >,\big <(123)\big >$

Let me choose $H=\big <(12)\big >=\{1,(12)\}, J=\big <(23)\big >=\{1,(23)\} ,  K=\big <(13)\big >=\{1,(13)\}$

So how do we compute these:

$[[H,J],K] \qquad$ and $[H,[J,K]]$

Comment: You mean what the notation $(*)$ means?

Comment: I meant the notation $[ ]$ @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Surely, this notation has been introduced in the book that posed the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $[H,K]$ generalizes the commutator subgroup and is given by
$$
[H,K]=\langle hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\mid h\in H,k\in K\rangle.
$$
This can be applied succesively. For a reference see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Commutator_of_two_subgroups).

Concerning the title question, list all subgroups $H$ ,$J$, $K$ of $S_3$ and compute $[H,[J,K]]$ and $[[H,J],K]$, i.e., first compute $[H,J]$ for all choices, and then iterate.

Comment: Can you check my edit please? @DietrichBurde

Comment: You mean, "tSo how do we compute this: $[H,1]$"? This is easy. All commutators are given there by $h\cdot1\cdot h^ {-1}\cdot 1^{-1}=h\cdot h^{-1}=1$.

Comment: But with choices I made for H,J,K it doesn't work out, all I got is 1=1

Comment: I see. Then try other choices. Compute $[H,K]$ by the above formula.